# How to compile python with modified OpenSSL (with russian GOST support)?

Tags: python, linux, ssl, openssl, gost3410

I am trying to force python 2.7 works with modified openssl library. I need to support russian GOST ciphers. So I configurated OpenSSL like this

```
./config shared zlib enable-rfc3779 --prefix=/my/path/
```

and installed it (make depend, make, make test, make install). openssl.conf contains

```
openssl_conf = openssl_def
[openssl_def]
engines = engine_section
[engine_section]
gost = gost_section
[gost_section]
engine_id = gost
default_algorithms = ALL
```

After that command `/my/path/bin/openssl ciphers | tr ":" "\n" | grep GOST` returns

```
GOST2001-GOST89-GOST89
GOST94-GOST89-GOST89
```

and `openssl s_client -connect test.domain.ru:443` connected succesfully and I can send GET requests (standart OpenSSL doesn't work with this site in this way). After that I tried to compile python with that openssl lib: I uncomment and changed SSL variable in Modules/Setup.dist to `/my/path` and related lines under it and also changed `ssl_incs` and `ssl_libs` variable in setup.py. I have installed python to my home folder and running scripts form that folder. But when I run script like that

```
import urllib2
print(urllib2.urlopen('https://test.domain.ru/').read())
```

I still got error

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:501: error:140920F8:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown cipher returned>
```

What should I do to force python use new OpenSSL (gost engine) and may be there is any simple way to do that?

OS: Linux Mint 17 x64

Comment: You should change "compile python" to something less confusing. Probably to "integrate Python with custom modification of openssl".

Comment: If you're in Linux, and you're modified SSL/TLS library has the same file name as the system version but in some other directory, you can test it by overriding the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable temporarily.  Something like (assuming the new one is in the current directory) like this prefixed to your python command:  LD_LIBARARY_PATH=.    An easy example is to copy some other *.so file to ./libc.so.6 and get "ls" to break.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rebuild _ssl.pyd with some changes in  Modules/_ssl.c.
1) add #include  after lines

```
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>
```

2) add OPENSSL_config(NULL); before lines

```
SSL_library_init();
SSL_load_error_strings();
```

inside init_ssl function.